# Returning different values of the same data type:

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a `readValue` function that can return any of `Value`'s algebraic data types. The value constructors for `Value` aren't exported, so how can I return a `Value`?

Here's the [documentation on Value](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bson-0.1.1/docs/Data-Bson.html#t%3aValue).

Below is the function and the errors it produces:

```
readValue :: Label -> String -> Value
readValue label valueString =
  case label of
    "tags" -> (read valueString :: [String])
    "text" -> (read valueString :: String)


src/Edit.hs:79:16:
    Couldn't match type `Char' with `[Char]'
    Expected type: [String]
      Actual type: String
    In the expression: (read valueString :: String)
    In a case alternative: "text" -> (read valueString :: String)
    In the expression:
      case label of {
        "tags" -> (read valueString :: [String])
        "text" -> (read valueString :: String) }
```

Comment: `Value` is a single algebraic data type and its constructors _are_ exported by the module you linked to. And at least the first error is very clear.

Comment: Also, it looks like you can use the `val` function from the `Val` typeclass to create `Value` values. E.g. `val (3.0 :: Double)` will create a BSON Float value.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. Now the only issue is that I'm trying to create a `Field` via `Label =: Val a`, but `Value` is not an instance of `Val`. Do I have to wrap the `Value` in a `Maybe`, which is an instance of `Val`? That seems awkward, given that I'll never store `Nothing`, and I'll always have to pattern match needlessly when I retrieve the `Value` from the `Field`.

Comment: Just use `Field`'s `:=` constructor directly? Or is that one also somehow not in scope?

Comment: Whenever I use BSON I write an orphan `instance Val Value where` because it has a pretty obvious implementation as you noted. I've even added a pull request to the repository for this purpose, but it's sat untouched: https://github.com/mongodb/bson-haskell/pull/1.

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
readValue :: Label -> Value
```

You want:

```
readValue :: Label -> String -> Value
```

But:

```
(read valueString :: [String])
```

Has type `[String]` because that’s the type you gave it explicitly. Recall that `::` has the lowest precedence. So the compiler is trying to unify `String -> [String]` with `Value`. That’s the source of your first error. The second error is caused by the `:: String` annotation on the second branch of the `case`, asking the compiler to try to unify `String` with `[String]`, which too fails.

I suppose you want to wrap these values you’ve read into some of the `Value` constructors, which are indeed exported by `Data.Bson`, else you would be trying to return multiple different types from one function. But without knowing more about your problem, I can’t infer what you meant to do.

Comment: My apologies, the first error is actually irrelevant. I deleted it. When I try to use one of `Value`'s value constructors, namely `Array`, I get this error: `Not in scope: type constructor or class `Array'`

Comment: @RosePerrone It sounds very likely that you imported `Value` incorrectly. But no one could see that, because you didn't show your imports. Specifically, it sounds like you used `import Data.Bson (..., Value, ...)`, which imports only the type, not the constructors. To get the constructors too, you would use `import Data.Bson (..., Value(..), ...)`.  (Note the difference between `..`, which is syntax, and ..., which I used to indicate elisions.)

Comment: I used `import Data.Bson`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution:

```
instance Val Value where
  val   = id
  cast' = Just

readValue :: Label -> String -> Value
readValue label valueString =
  case label of
    "tags" -> val (read valueString :: [String])
    "text" -> val  (read valueString :: String)
```